# How to create multiple tables(Entities) in app engine datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have created example entity "Shout" successfully by following some tutorial on app engine datastore. but when i tried to create Register table (Followed same steps i did to create "Shout") but its not creating.

Actually in my application i have Register page and the user's registration data should be stored in "Register" Table and later for login i retrieve uname and pwd to match it with user entered data from login page. Please Help Me. how can i do this.

This is what i am trying...

```
import wsgiref.handlers
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template


class Register(db.Model):
    username=db.StringProperty(required="true")
    email=db.StringProperty(required="true")
    password=db.StringProperty(required="true")
    cpassword=db.StringProperty(required="true")


class Shout(db.Model):
    message=db.StringProperty(required="true")
    when = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add="true")
    who = db.StringProperty()


class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        shouts= db.GqlQuery('select * from Register order by when desc')
        values={'shouts':shouts}
        self.response.out.write(template.render('ui.html',values))

    def post(self):
        shoutt= Register(username=self.request.get('txt1'),email=self.request.get('txt2'),password=self.request.get('txt3'),cpassword=self.request.get('txt4'))
        shoutt.put()
        self.redirect('/')

class SecondPage(webapp.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):
        sec= db.GqlQuery('select * from Shout order by when desc')
        values={'sec':sec}
        self.response.out.write(template.render('login.html',values))




application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),('/second', SecondPage)],    debug=True)



def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: There are no tables and appengine is not SQL and it is important not to think in those terms.

You aren't including enough informnation in your question, in what way is it not working, do you get an error, have is the `post` method getting called, are you getting an 404?  Try putting logging in the code to see if the sections you expect get called.  Include your handler definition from app.yaml here.  Try doing some debugging using pdb, to see what is going on.